# Share intent to used recent or often-used contacts

Tags: share-menu, direct-share

Some of my Android apps allows me to share to oft-used (or recent?) contacts, which is quite convenient.

**What is this feature called?** I'm having a hard time finding information about this "direct share" feature on the [API developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html).

[image]

*(The reason I want to know what it's called is so I can make a feature request to my receipt scanner app people, so I don't have to type receipts@myaccountants each and every time)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called *Direct Share* and described here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#direct-share

> This release provides you with APIs to make sharing intuitive and quick for users. You can now define direct share targets that launch a specific activity in your app. These direct share targets are exposed to users via the Share menu. This feature allows users to share content to targets, such as contacts, within other apps. For example, the direct share target might launch an activity in another social network app, which lets the user share content directly to a specific friend or community in that app.